# the signe of a term

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ two real numbers such that $\alpha<0$ and $\beta >0$  and $\alpha+\beta >0 $

and let be $Z\ \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|Z|$ the complex modulus of $Z$

what can i said about the sign of $\alpha |Z|^2+\beta |Z^2|$  ?

Comment: Note that $|Z|^2 = |Z^2|$.

Comment: i know it's a norm but after doing the calculs i cant find this , so i am little confused

Comment: The answer below should be of help to you.

Comment: If $x,y\in \Bbb R$ and $i^2=-1$ then $(x+iy)^2=x^2+2xiy +i^2y^2\;=$ $\;x^2+2xiy-y^2=a+ib $ where $a=x^2-y^2\in \Bbb R $ and $ b=2xy\in \Bbb R.$.... Therefore $|(x+i y)^2|\;=$ $\;|a+ib|=\;$ $\; \sqrt {a^2+b^2}\;=$ $\;\sqrt {(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}\;=$ $\;\sqrt {(x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4)+4x^2y^2}\;=$$\;\sqrt {x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4}\;=$ $\;\sqrt {(x^2+y^2)^2}\;=$ $\;x^2+y^2\;=$ $\;|x+iy|^2.$

Comment: In general for any $z_1,z_2\in \Bbb C$ we have $|z_1z_2|=|z_1|\cdot |z_2|.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\alpha |Z|^2+\beta |Z^2| = \alpha |Z|^2+\beta |Z|^2 = (\alpha+\beta) |Z|^2$ is positive and strictly positive provided $Z\not=0$.